# How to print out tracing message in Substrate runtime development

Tags: substrate

When working on [Parity Substrate](https://substrate.dev/) runtime development, how can I print out debug message for tracing and inspecting my variables?

Comment: You tagged your question with `substrate`, would you be interested in a dedicated Stack Exchange Q&A site for Substrate, Polkadot, et al. -- check out the [Area51 Substrate Proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122626/substrate?referrer=NTUwMTkxYjJjOTJiNjE0YzMxYjgwMGNkZmFlYzdhZTczYjk1ZWY3ZGI4NzJmODUwN2RlYTQ2MTNjZTdkOTZhMAzuL-zybtPN9CHzwE-WUdvBC8WxvPG46b4ayadke6kG0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of the above answers are correct in their own sense/time. Here's a more accurate overview:

- `runtime_io::print("...");` has been moved. You can now use the same function from [`sp-runtime::print()`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_runtime/fn.print.html). These will be visible in a log target named `runtime` and level `DEBUG`. So you'd have to do `RUST_LOG=runtime=debug`. You are still calling into [`sp_io` under the hood though]. Similar functions are provided un [`frame_support::print`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/fn.print.html) and [`frame_support::debug`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/fn.debug.html) as well.
- If you want to have more control over the log target/level, you can either directly use the `log` crate. Similarly, you need to make sure that you are enabling the appropriate log target via `RUST_LOG`. Be ware that you if you forget to specify the log target in `log`, the crate path will be used by default.
- If you want to compile for wasm and native, and want prints only for native execution, use [`sp_std::if_std!{}`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_std/macro.if_std.html) macro.

A final useful tip is to: when possible, you can just bloat your code with `println!` and do `SKIP_WASM_BUILD=1 cargo run [xxx]`. This is helpful when you are developing and want quick debug prints without any of the setup explained above.

Comment: if you want to print logs to your terminal output to debug the value of variables when running tests for a specific pallet, you can run add the following in a function of your pallet `println!("<INSERT_MESSAGE> {:#?}", <INSERT_VARIABLE_NAME>);`, and then run the tests with `SKIP_WASM_BUILD=1 RUST_LOG=runtime=debug cargo test --package <INSERT_PALLET_NAME> -- --nocapture`

Comment: @LukeSchoen your answer should be the best, up-to-date answer! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `if_std!` macro included with `sp-std`:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/2979

`if_std!` is a feature gate that should only be run when `std` feature is enabled.

## Example

```
sp_std::if_std! {
    // This code is only being compiled and executed when the `std` feature is enabled.
    println!("Hello native world");
}
```

This is better because you can `println` variables and stuff rather than simply printing a string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [log](https://crates.io/crates/log) crate, add it to your cargo.toml and use it like this:

```
log::info!("hello {}",substrate);
```

source : https://docs.substrate.io/test/debug/

Answer (score 0):

As a newcomer to Substrate development, the most direct way I found is with `runtime_io::print()`.

Example:

```rust
use runtime_io::{ self };

decl_module! {
  pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
    fn deposit_event<T>() = default;

    pub fn my_func(origin) -> Result {
      runtime_io::print("Hello World");
      Ok(());
    }
  }
}
```

The message will then appear in the console. Pay quick attention to it as it is constantly scrolling.

For a complete example, refer to the [TCR tutorial example in github](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-tcr/blob/master/runtime/src/tcr.rs).

Comment: This answer is no longer valid and goes back to prior to crates renames in substrate.